# Basic CMakefile question for building OpenCV

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am a novice in C++ programming, now having to build the OpenCV from source. I am getting an error related to the cudatoolkit installation

```
[ 13%] Built target opencv_cudev
[ 13%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Path to libdevice library not specified
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake:266 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/bruce/opencv-4.2.0/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
```

I look inside the `cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake` file and see the following lines.

```
# Generate the code
cuda_execute_process(
  "Generating ${generated_file}"
  COMMAND "${CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE}"
  "${source_file}"
  ${format_flag} -o "${generated_file}"
  ${CCBIN}
  ${nvcc_flags}
  ${nvcc_host_compiler_flags}
  ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}
  -DNVCC
  ${CUDA_NVCC_INCLUDE_ARGS}
  )
```

I want to dig into where it's looking for the libdevice library. I don't know the technique for printing out the meaning of all these parameters. How do I print them out as I execute `make`?

Comment: If you are using `make`, then you can run `make --just-print`. It will print on your console all commands that it intends to issue, instead of executing them. This will start from the current state of your build, so the easy way to find what's wrong with some specific build step is to first run `make` to see it fail, and after that run `make --just-print`: you will see the problematic command on top.

Comment: Try running `make VERBOSE=1`. For CMake-generated Makefiles it will turn on full command echoing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug this, and print the values in each of these CMake variables, you can add the [`message`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/message.html) command to this CMake file:

```
# Generate the code
cuda_execute_process(
  "Generating ${generated_file}"
  COMMAND "${CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE}"
  "${source_file}"
  ${format_flag} -o "${generated_file}"
  ${CCBIN}
  ${nvcc_flags}
  ${nvcc_host_compiler_flags}
  ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}
  -DNVCC
  ${CUDA_NVCC_INCLUDE_ARGS}
  )

# Print all the above variables to the console.
message("generated_file: ${generated_file}")
message("CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE: ${CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE}")
message("source_file: ${source_file}")
message("format_flag: ${format_flag}")
message("CCBIN: ${CCBIN}")
message("nvcc_flags: ${nvcc_flags}")
message("nvcc_host_compiler_flags: ${nvcc_host_compiler_flags}")
message("CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS: ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
message("CUDA_NVCC_INCLUDE_ARGS: ${CUDA_NVCC_INCLUDE_ARGS}")
```

If you can modify how `cmake` is called from the command line, you can add the `trace-expand` [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) to print all the CMake calls, and expand the variables used:

```
cmake --trace-expand ..
```